# Ofstream doesn't seem to be outputting

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

So I am trying to create a log for a calculator so I can go back and check to make sure all the entered numbers were put in correctly. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream f;
    f.open("pumpout.txt");

    float number = 0;
    float total = 0;
    char operand;
    bool running = true;

    cin >> total;
    f << total << " ";
    cin >> operand;
    f << operand << " ";
    cin >> number;
    f << number << " = ";

    while (running = true) {

        if (operand == '/') {
            total = total / number;
            cout << total << endl;
            f << total << "\n" << total << " ";
            cin >> operand;
        }
        else if (operand == '*') {
            total = total * number;
            cout << total << endl;
            f << total << "\n" << total << " ";
            cin >> operand;
        }
        else if (operand == '+') {
            total = total + number;
            cout << total << endl;
            f << total << "\n" << total << " ";
            cin >> operand;
        }
        else if (operand == '-') {
            total = total - number;
            cout << total << endl;
            f << total << "\n" << total << " ";
            cin >> operand;
        } 
        f << operand << " ";
        cin >> number;
        f << number << " = ";
    }
}
```

So It adds and does everything the way I want it to, but It will not go to the text file.  The format should be:

```
total operand # = total
```

Through the entire text file. any help would be great.

Comment: **the pumput.txt is supposed to be Logs.txt**

Comment: When is the loop supposed to stop?

Comment: This is wrong `while (running = true) {` first you used `=` instead of `==`, secondly `while (running == true) {` is just the same as `while (running) {`.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are not seeing any output because your loop never stops and your file never closes. If you want output to appear in a file immediately you should *flush* the file with `std::flush` or `std::endl`, e.g. `f << total << "\n" << total << " " << flush;`.

For efficiency reasons file output is *buffered*, which means that file output is first written to a buffer, it does not immediately appear in the file. Flushing is a process that takes the buffer and writes it immediately to the file.